# Download multiple files consecutively in background using swift and Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, alamofire

I'm developing an app with Xcode 6.3, Swift 1 and Alamofire which download multiple files consecutively. I start new download when the previous one was finished and I want to it works in background. My problem is: in debug mode and when the device is attached to Xcode, it works fine. But when become disconnected it doesn't continue download in background. Any suggestion that what would my problem be?
Thanks in proceed

Comment: Do you mean "consecutively"?

Comment: @Mundi yes, accept my apology because of my poor English, I corrected that. Thanks

Comment: @Mundi what if we first set the startRequestsImmediately to false and create all download requests instances in an array then call resume consecutively? I think it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start a new download in the background. You will need to either

- finish the download after the app is back up again or
- change your server logic to combine the multiple downloads into one big download. Then you have a chance that it might complete, but it is not guaranteed.